# How should I close this jquery IFrame?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, cookies

I am building a popup-like page, which could be included into other sites. I use cookies (created with PHP commands) and I would like to set that this popup shows up only once in a while (so the cookies would be timed).

I am using bPopup for the popup window, so it's Jquery based. The problem is that i cannot close it.
I managed to make the content not loading in case there is a cookie, but i cannot find anny command to close the popup.

I have googled a lot, tried with parent.closeIFrame, but that didn't worked.

Do you have any idea how could i code this?

Here are the code parts:

```
<!-- Element to pop up -->

<div id="element_to_pop_up">
    <a href="#"class="b-close" style="position:absolute; margin-top:5px; margin-left:550px;"><img src="./image/close.png"><a/>
    <iframe frameBorder="0" name="iFrame" width="600" height="500" src="welcome.php" scrolling="no"></iframe>

</div>
```

The welcome.php is a simply html file with analytics, so there's no much possibilities.

I managed it with an exit command to get an empty popup window in case there is cookie found, but i cannot hide the whole window, which would be annoying for the users to get into the same popup over and over again.

Please help me finding a great solution for this case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You won't be able to set a cookie on the site that shows your iframe in a popup. But (I guess) since you will provide them with the code to show the popup, you could also join a little script that creates a cookie on their side, so that the popup doesn't show.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use `iframe`?

Comment: @Skwal : I made some changes on it. Now it creates cookie on the load page, and it reads it there too. The problem is that it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Michal : It seemed to be the best solution in this case. It would be a third party app that costumers can add to their sites.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://dinbror.dk/blog/bPopup/#Options)

**Public Function**

```
close()
```

Closes the popup.

**Usage:**

```
$('element_to_pop_up').bPopup().close(); // Version 0.4.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea @Tomanow!
I have edited some things in the code, but it doesn't seem to work. Do you have any idea what shall I modify to make it working correctly?

`<script>;(function($) {
   var cvalue = $.cookie('xVisited');
   if (cvalue != true) {
            $(window).bind('load', function (e) {
         
        $(function() {

            
   

                 
                e.preventDefault();

                

     $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup();
     
     }
    

    )}
    

    )}
 else {
     $.cookie('xVisited', 'true');
    }
    })(jQuery);
</script>`